# Finding an expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

I have $n$ dots in a circle and $n$ edges that connect these dots.

Each dot is painted red or blue in a probability of $0.5$ each.

An edge is blue/red if both the dots it connects are blue/red.

Let $N$ be the number of red edges, find $E(N)$.

Can anyone give me a *hint* as to how to approach this? I thought about binomial probability for $N$ with $n$ and $0.5^2$ but the chances for success if the $2$ edges share a dot is $0.5^3$ not $0.5^4$ so thats not going to work.

Again I would like a **hint** not a **solution**.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know only the number of edges or the edges themselves?

Comment: I dont understand your question...